# What would cause itermittent internet connectivity on my server?

Tags: networking, network-interface, internet

I occasionally have trouble with an ubuntu VM I set up for testing developement work - it occasionally becomes inaccessible to ssh, can't connect to archive.ubuntu.com for updates, etc. It has two network interfaces, an external one with a public IP `eth0`, and and internal one `eth1` with a 10.0.x.x IP for talking to other VMs in the hypervisor group.

I noted today after booting it and being unable to ssh in and `apt-get update` (so I log in via the web console to debug), that when I try to ping example.com, it tries to do so via `eth1` (presumably because `eth0` has no connectivity, despite being `up` according to `ifup`)

If I do a `traceroute` it does go all the way to the datacenter. `sshd` is verified to be running. VM firewall accepting traffic on port 22 for `eth0`. Here's an extract from `iptables -S`:

```
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -s eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

What's really confusing is that the problem isn't deterministically reproducible. I can get a lucky boot and connectivity will work, but sometimes, without touching the settings, it doesn't. Any ideas on how to debug this?

---

Edit: extract from `/etc/network/interfaces` - no dhcp. I'm terrible at networking, so I wanted to check: is there anything here that indicates weird routing preferences?

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address x.x.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.128
    broadcast x.x.x.127
    network x.x.x.0
    gateway  x.x.x.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.0.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.128
    broadcast 10.0.0.255
    network 10.0.0.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1
```

Should I add the following lines to `eth0`?

```
up route add x.x.x.1 dev eth0
up route add default gw x.x.x.1
```

Comment: Without error logs, ifconfig outputs when down, traceroutes and interface configuration details, the answer can be quite broad.

Comment: If the machine tries to use the `10.0.x.x` interface for internet traffic, then you've almost certainly got a DHCP server on that network which is advertising a default gateway, and this is just a simple race condition of which DHCP server responds first. Either configure that DHCP server not to send a default route, or configure your client to ignore it.

Comment: I've added `/etc/network/interfaces` - it's not explicitly using dhcp. Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Oh, I made a bad assumption. I assumed you wouldn't have put a default gateway statement on 2 static interface definitions. Yeah, don't do that. Remove one of them.